# Unmet Dependencies preventing any upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, apt

I'm using Linux Mint 14. Whenever I try to install or upgrade anything using apt-get, I get the following message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
google-chrome-stable : 
Depends: libnss3 (>= 3.17.2) but 3.15.4-0ubuntu0.12.10.2 is to be installed
Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.8.0) but 4.7.2-2ubuntu1 is to be installed                    
Depends: lsb-base (>= 4.1) but 4.0-0ubuntu26.2 is to be installed
```

Google Chrome seems to work fine and nothing I do seems to fix this problem  Any update just finishes with this message.

I've tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  audacity-data avidemux-common avidemux-plugins-common fgfs-aircraft-base fgfs-base fgfs-scenery-base lame libaften0 libalut0
  libavidemux0 libenet1a libflac++6 libirrlicht1.7a libmlt++3 libmlt-data libmlt5 libplib1 libportsmf0 libsbsms10 melt mjpegtools
  openshot-doc python-mlt5 simgear2.6.0 stellarium-data supertuxkart-data twolame
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED
  google-chrome-stable
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 178 MB disk space will be freed.
```

This just deleted Chrome which I need

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net nadia Release.gpg
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net nadia Release                                     
Get:1 http://dl.bintray.com jessie Release.gpg [821 B]                         
Get:2 http://dl.bintray.com jessie Release [9,496 B]                            
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia Release.gpg                          
Hit http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia Release                              
Get:3 http://dl.bintray.com jessie/main amd64 Packages [1,790 B]
Get:4 http://dl.bintray.com jessie/main i386 Packages [1,790 B]                                                              
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                                 
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net nadia/main Sources                       
  404  Not Found
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/upstream amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net nadia/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net nadia/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net nadia/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net nadia/main Translation-en
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/import amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/upstream i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://dl.bintray.com jessie/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://dl.bintray.com jessie/main Translation-en
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/import i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/main amd64 Packages                                                                       
Hit http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/upstream amd64 Packages                                                                   
Hit http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/import amd64 Packages                                                                     
Hit http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/main i386 Packages                                                                        
Hit http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/upstream i386 Packages                                                                    
Hit http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/import i386 Packages                                                                      
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/import Translation-en_GB                                                                  
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/import Translation-en                                                                     
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/main Translation-en_GB                                                                    
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/main Translation-en                                                                       
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/upstream Translation-en_GB                                                                
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com nadia/upstream Translation-en                                                                   
Fetched 13.9 kB in 9s (1,537 B/s)                                                                                                 
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/nadia/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/nadia/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/nadia/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Doesn't help either.

Also tried the following based on suggestion in the comments:

```
sudo apt-get install lsb-base libstdc++6 libnss3


Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
lsb-base is already the newest version.
libnss3 is already the newest version.
libstdc++6 is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libnss3 (>= 3.17.2) but 3.15.4-0ubuntu0.12.10.2 is to be installed
                        Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.8.0) but 4.7.2-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
                        Depends: lsb-base (>= 4.1) but 4.0-0ubuntu26.2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I need my PC for work, and am incredibly busy so just don't have time to upgrade to a newer version of Mint which would be my prefered option.  Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Per the logs, `sudo apt-get -f install`, is clearly what removed Chrome not `sudo apt-get update`.  I assume you have attempted to install Chrome again and force (-f) the install?

Comment: When chrome was deleted I couldn't then get it to reinstall due to unmet dependencies which I couldn't solve. After anout 90mins of trying stuff, chrome worked again, though dpkg etc. thinks it is broken. I don't want to risk uninstalling it again as it is my ma8n tool for work

Comment: simply using `sudo apt-get install lsb-base libstdc++6 libnss3` should solve your original problem.  This comment is based on the answer to this question: [Cannot Install Google Chrome. How do I fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/220960/cannot-install-google-chrome-how-do-i-fix-it) which has a nearly identical output just for Ubuntu.  You might also have to add a specialize (universe) repository, I have no idea what it will be for Mint, but I suspect the same one can be used.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, just tried that and that didn't work either ````already the newest version```` - see edits above

Comment: you ran the wrong command. its `sudo apt-get install -f`. Thats how i do it every time. the `-f` AFTER the `install` is to fix the dependencies.